# Java - Race condition on two arrays access

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, queue, synchronized

Let me introduce the following scenario.

I have **t** threads performing *reading operations* on an array **A** that contains **n** points (of **d** dimension), each thread receives an interval [i, j] of points such that: j - i = n / t. Those threads also perform *writing operations* on one or multiple sets **S** (each set containing a list and a point of d dimension). Adding a point in a set would mean adding it in its list and incrementing its point by the given one.

The thread job is to add each point (it received) in a specific set according to some conditions.

Based on the tools I have at my disposal (please see **[1]**) I see two ways of doing it.

Either (with p: a point and s: a set),

1. I lock s.list, add p, unlock s.list.
2. I lock s.point, set s.point to the sum of p with the s.point, unlock s.point.

---

Or (considering 1. - 2. - ... as a *task*),

- While there are still task to do.

  1. I try to lock s.list.

     - If yes, add p, unlock s.list.
     - If no, add 1. to task.
  2. I try to lock s.point[0]

     - If yes, set s.point[0] to the sum of p[0] with s.point[0], unlock s.point[0].
     - If no, add 2. to task.
  3. I try to lock s.point[1]

     - If yes, set s.point[1] to the sum of p[1] with s.point[1], unlock s.point[1].
     - If no, add 2. to task.
  4. ...
  5. I try to lock s.point[d-1]

     - If yes, set s.point[d-1] to the sum of p[d-1] with s.point[d-1], unlock s.point[d-1].
     - If no, add D. to task.

Is it worth it to use the second solution? Why (if not)?

**[1]** Please note that I can only use non-depricated methods of the `Thread` class, synchronized-wait-notify facitilities and `ReentrantLock` class. Use of any other class from `util.concurrent.*` is prohibited, and so is *re-implementation*.

Comment: Instead of locking, did you look at the concurrent collections, e.g. using `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` instead of `ArrayList`, and `AtomicInteger` for the sum?

Comment: Really sorry I forgot to add that I'm really limited with the use of libraries, please consider the last point I added. Otherwise atomics would have been my very best solution.

Comment: Your scenario description is incomplete or very confusing. First you say the threads only perform reading operations on a slice of the array, but then suddenly you start talking about inserts. It is hard to visualize your data structures and the operations on them just using your description.

Comment: I've updated my scenario, hope it is a bit clearer now.